# Вызов метода класса

Tags: php

Есть 3 файла.
**index.php**

```
include "func.php";

$vk = new vk_api(VK_KEY, VERSION);
$vk->sendOK(); 
...
$testq = ttt($peer_id, $message);
```

**func.php**

```
include "api/vk_api.php"; 

function ttt($peer_id, $text)
{
    $t = $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, $text);
}
```

**vk_api.php**

```
class vk_api
{
    public function sendMessage($sendID, $message){
        if (!empty($sendID)) {
            return $this->request($this->token, 'messages.send', array('message'=>$message, 'peer_id'=>$sendID, 'random_id'=>rand(1, 2147483600)));
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
 }
```

Но **request** в **sendMessage** почему то не вызывается, больше того, останавливается дальнейшее выполнение кода.

Если же вызывать напрямую из файла **index.php**

```
$vk = new vk_api(VK_KEY, VERSION);
$vk->sendOK(); 
...
$vk->sendMessage('123', 'test');
```

То все работает. 
В чем может быть проблема? 
Как правильно вызывать методы класса из функции другого файла?

Comment: `Но sendMessage не вызывается` - во-первых, смотрим ошибку и переводим, в 90% случаев там всё написано что не работает и легко исправить. Во-вторых, вы в функцию передавайте и экземпляр класса. А вообще, на ооп переделайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все переменные в `php` по умолчанию являются **локальными**, и **не могут** быть использованы в пользовательских функциях. Чтобы избавится от этого нужно сделать эту переменную **глобальной**:

**func.php**

```
include "api/vk_api.php"; 
function ttt($peer_id, $text)
{
    global $vk;
    $t = $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, $text);
}
```

---

Так же, вы можете передавать эту переменную в функцию. Тогда код будет выглядеть как-то так:

**index.php**

```
include "func.php";

$vk = new vk_api(VK_KEY, VERSION);
$vk->sendOK(); 
...
$testq = ttt($peer_id, $message, $vk);
```

**func.php**

```
include "api/vk_api.php"; 
function ttt($peer_id, $text, $vk)
{
    $t = $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, $text);
}
```